# AppEngine Sandbox

Tags: java, google, sandbox

Does anyone know how the AppEngine sandbox is implemented? I heard they use a SecurityManager with Java but surely they are using another layer as well like LXC. I've looked at the [whitelist](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist) and there are a lot of classes that:

- commonly used in exploit chains because they have security flaws that Oracle refuse to fix (ScriptEngine)
- had numerous security problems recently and still quite a big unknown (java.lang.invoke.*)
- had security issues recently and in the past (java.util.concurrent.*, javax.xml.transform.Templates)

I'm interested in running stuff on appengine but if they are only using the SecurityManager then I think they have a huge problem with security.

Comment: It's more than likely as thorough as technically possible. http://cloudsecurity.org/blog/2008/07/01/cloudsecurityorg-interviews-guido-van-rossum-google-app-engine-python-and-security.html

Answer (score 1):

I think it might help with the last part of your question if I point out that the main point of AppEngine security in Python was protecting THEM, not US. I previously read a paper that did have quite a few specifics. At one point, someone specifically said the AppEngine security modifications were to keep customers' scripts from damaging Google's host systems. Stopping malice in general in customer-submitted applications or protecting customer applications from hacker attacks was still an open, unsolved problem.

I'd expect they have the same goals and limitations in the Java runtime.